# Filter out spark dataframe rows which do not have certain nested fields in Java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have below sample row in spark dataframe.

```
{
    "id":"B07H3MVTSN",
    "mid":4,
    "inner":{
      "type1":[{
          "cid":"B06XVVSLX8"
        },
        {
          "cid":"B06XJ2JZ2Z"
        }
      ],
      "type2":[{
          "cid":"B06XVVSLX1"
        },
        {
          "cid":"B06XJ2JZ22"
        }
      ],
      "type3":[{
          "cid":"B06XVVSLX3"
        },
        {
          "cid":"B06XJ2JZ24"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have a list of strings which can be {"type1","type2"}.

I want to filter out(get rid of) rows from the dataframe which do not have either of those two fields. How to add filter() condition which checks existence of nested struct fields from a set of values from a list

e.g below sample row should be removed using filter condition since it does not contain type1 and type2

```
{
        "id":"B07H3MVTS1",
        "mid":4,
        "inner":{
          "type3":[{
              "cid":"B06XVVSLX3"
            },
            {
              "cid":"B06XJ2JZ24"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

Schema for the above data  can be seen in below method getSchema()

```
private StructType getSchema(){

        ArrayType types = DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("cid", DataTypes.StringType, false)
                }));

        StructType inner = DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("type1", types, true), DataTypes.createStructField("type2", types, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("type3", types, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("type4", types, true)
                });

        return DataTypes.createStructType(
                new StructField[] {
                        DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("mid", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("inner", inner, false)
                });
    }
```

Comment: can you share the schema of your dataframe?

Comment: @koiralo : Updated schema description in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `filter` the list of fields with `isNotNull` function as below, adjust the filter condition as per your need

```
val fields = List("type1", "type2")

val filter = fields.map(f => col(s"inner.$f").isNotNull).reduce(_ or _)

df.filter(filter).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|id        |inner                                                                                     |mid|
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|B07H3MVTSN|{[{B06XVVSLX8}, {B06XJ2JZ2Z}], [{B06XVVSLX1}, {B06XJ2JZ22}], [{B06XVVSLX3}, {B06XJ2JZ24}]}|4  |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is there null value in the inner struct? is it type3 and type4?  If the first sample row and second sample row is my input data, then  will df.filter give me only the first sample row as it contains type1 and type2.

Comment: Yes they were from the inner struct value, please check now updated as per the question

Comment: Awesome. Do you know the equivalent code for  `fields.map(f => col(s"inner.$f").isNotNull).reduce(_ or _)` in Java

Comment: Not tested but something like this should be equivalent 

       ` List<String> list = Arrays.asList("type1", "type2");

        Optional<Column> reduce = list.stream().map(f -> col("inner." + f).isNotNull()).reduce((f1, f2) -> f1.or(f2));`